# python selenium - using phantomJS proxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, proxy, web-scraping

I am trying to figure out how to use *phantomJS* proxy server.
I would like to use a URL proxy (http://multiwebproxy.com/:8080) to test my *phantomJS* ability to web scrape anonymously. So far I tried to use the following code unsuccessfully.

**Any ideas for free \ paid proxy service which is compatible with Selenium phantomJS?**

```
PROXY = 'http://multiwebproxy.com/:8080'

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)

dcap['proxy'] = {
"httpProxy":PROXY,
"ftpProxy":PROXY,
"sslProxy":PROXY,
"noProxy":None,
"proxyType":"MANUAL",
"class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
"autodetect":False
}

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'/home/ec2-user/utils/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs',desired_capabilities=dcap)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can use a proxy with PhantomJS in selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

myProxy = "http://multiwebproxy.com/:8080"

proxy = Proxy({
  'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
  'httpProxy': myProxy,
  'ftpProxy': myProxy,
  'sslProxy': myProxy,
  'noProxy':''})

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(proxy=proxy)
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know Python, but in C# there is a class called `PhantomJSOptions`, where you can call `AddAdditionalCapability()` with param `CapabilityType.Proxy`.

Example:

```
private PhantomJSDriver CreatePhantomJSDriver(string httpProxy)
{
    var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpProxy))
    {
        options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, new Proxy { HttpProxy = httpProxy });
    }
    return new PhantomJSDriver(options);
}
```